# Grep to escape special characters

Tags: regex, shell, unix, sed, grep

Hello i am new to shell scripting i am facing the following problems

1 > how do i grep to find words with " or ' or both in a word in a file which is large

i tried

```
grep "'\|"" foo.txt
```

which does not work

2 > Take one file which consist of a text and print entire lines of another file where that text is present
example

File 1 contains

```
abc
def
lmo
```

file 2 contains

```
amn,abc
abc,amd
fgh,def
abd,lmo
```

Match the text in file 1 and 2nd column of file 2 and print the entire line of file 2

```
desired output
amn,abc
fgh,def
abd,lmo
```

Comment: The second question can be very easily solved using `awk`. There are many answers already which solve such problem. Try them out. You will get better responses if you try out something and find difficulty in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use character classes to match `"` or `'` as

```
grep "['\"]"
```

**Example**

```
$ echo hello\" | grep "['\"]"
hello"
```

Comment: That's not a character class, it's a bracket expression containing a character list. A character class is a locale-independent named identifier for a group of characters (e.g. `[:alnum:]` for the set of alpha-numeric characters as defined by your locale), usually used within a bracket expression (e.g. `[[:alnum:]]`) and sometimes combined with other character classes and/or character ranges (e.g. `3-7`) and/or character lists (e.g. `&_#`) within the bracket expression (e.g. `[[:alnum:][:space:]3-7&_#]`).